# Prolog receiving Json post

Tags: json, http, post, prolog, swi-prolog

This is my first question in stackoverflow so, bear with me.

I'm tring to build a simple Prolog api that receives json posts and after processing them, sends another json post back. I found this code to receive the json:

```
handle(Request) :-
    http_read_json_dict(Request, DictIn),
    compute(DictIn, DictOut),
    reply_json(DictOut).
```

I assume that `compute` is a custom predicate, which for test purposes is `test(D,D)`.

The problem is that when I try to test `handle(Request)` in swi-prolog I get either the error message `ERROR: atom_codes/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated` or I get false.

I assume I just have to pass a json in the `Request` but it's not working. I also tried sending a post with Postman with a json file in the body (raw and application/json) but i get a timeout, which eh..yea...
My question is what do I write in Request so that it instantiates it properly?

Thanks in advance and sorry if it's a bad/noobie question, but swi-prolog documentation is terrible and i can't find an answer anywhere.

Comment: I find swi-prolog documentation very good! Maybe you should read [Anne Ogborn's excellent tutorial](http://www.pathwayslms.com/swipltuts/html/)!

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I tried reading that tutorial but I coudnl't find any information regarding json requests and replies...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not too sure you fully understand how Prolog and swi-prolog's web framework works.

Here's a step-by-step mini-tutorial to get you started:

1. copy this in a file called `myserver.pl`:

   ```
   :- use_module(library(http/thread_httpd)).
   :- use_module(library(http/http_dispatch)).

   :- use_module(library(http/http_json)).

   :- http_handler(root(.),handle,[]).

   server(Port) :-
      http_server(http_dispatch,[port(Port)]).

   handle(Request) :-
      format(user_output,"I'm here~n",[]),
      http_read_json(Request, DictIn,[json_object(term)]),
      format(user_output,"Request is: ~p~n",[Request]),
      format(user_output,"DictIn is: ~p~n",[DictIn]),
      DictOut=DictIn,
      reply_json(DictOut).
   ```
2. launch swi-prolog and in the main repl type:

   ```
   [myserver].
   ```

   to consult your file. You should have no errors. Then launch your server, say on port 8000:

   ```
   server(8000).
   ```

   You should have the following reply:

   ```
   % Started server at http://localhost:8000/
   ```
3. open another terminal and post some json using `curl`:

   ```
   curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"hello":"world"}' http://localhost:8000
   ```

   you should have the following reply:

   ```
   {"hello":"world"}
   ```

   and in the running prolog you should see these messages:

   ```
   I'm here
   Request is: [protocol(http),peer(ip(127,0,0,1)),pool(client('httpd@8000',user:http_dispatch,<stream>(0x7facc4026b20),<stream>(0x7facc4027040))),input(<stream>(0x7facc4026b20)),method(post),request_uri(/),path(/),http_version(1-1),user_agent('curl/7.35.0'),host(localhost),port(8000),accept([media(_G841/_G842,[],1.0,[])]),content_type('application/json'),content_length(17)]
   DictIn is: json([hello=world])
   ```

If you do any modifications to the file `myserver.pl`, you just need to type `make.` in prolog's repl.

I can't recommend enough [Anne Ogborn's excellent tutorial](http://www.pathwayslms.com/swipltuts/html/). And by the way, swi-prolog's documentation is very good.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. That is extremely helpful. I'm very much an example driven learner and I find step by step instrucions the best way to understand what stuff does. The problem about swi-prolog documentation is that they only offer the description of each predicate and assume we know how to use them, which I don't. I'm still to find a good place for prolog implementation examples. Even google failed me this time.

Answer (score 0):

There are also a couple of JSON reader/writers around:

Thise modules take atoms and is implemented via DCG:
https://github.com/khueue/prolog-json/tree/master/src

This module is coded directively over ISO streams:
https://gist.github.com/jburse/63986bf525784d6d8cf99db132538d67#file-json_io-p

Both approaches don't require Prolog dicts and are suitable for a wide range of Prolog systems.